# Should I use semantic types instead of String in Java?

Tags: java, types

A library I am maintaining uses strings of various semantic meaning. For example one string is an invoice code and another one is a quotation code. There are docents of these semantic types and lookup methods depending on these types. In order to differentiate between the semantics of these values I started creating implementations of `CharSequence` called `InvoiceCode`, `QuotationCode` etc.

I used [Boost.Units](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_units.html) as an inspiration. There is absolutely no way around it when working with physical equations in C++. Using plain `double` will lead to unknown units very fast. I fear the same would happen when using `String` everywhere in my library.

Now my colleges are complaining that it's too cumbersome to convert from `String` to the semantic types before calling my library and than back to `String` when wanting to work with the results.

In my opinion my colleges should just use the appropriate types in their code.

So in the end the question boils down to: Is the use of semantic types instead of `String` recommended and/or common practice in Java?

Comment: This probably isn't a good question for stackoverflow.com, but it looks like a good question for programmers.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Do these classes perform any additional validation or have any additional semantics other than just holding a string value?

Comment: In my opinion, semantic types make code easier to understand and lead to less mistakes.  Your colleagues don't agree.  There's no factual answer.

Comment: @VivinPaliath the classes like `InvoiceCode` just do a syntactic validation (must not be empty, alpha numeric, no more than 30 characters). But there are methods to get the quotation on which an invoice is based. I have seen colleges just assuming the quotation would have the same code as the invoice therefore I wanted to make use of the type system.

Comment: @ajb if more people agree with you I will happily move the question :)

Comment: Would enums work?  That's more "standard" and might make your clients happier.

Comment: @user949300 Java enumerations would not work since the content is dynamic (order numbers, warehouse names etc.)

Answer (score 3):

C++ has two crucial features that make it much easier to work with user-defined semantic types - conversion operators and operator overloading. Java does not have either of the two, making your push for semantic types an uphill battle.

Your use of `CharSequence` interface makes it easier for users of your library to avoid conversion to string when getting the data from your library. However, passing you all these `InvoiceCode` and `QuotationCode` objects requires more work on the caller's side.

If the users always do this

```
source.yourMethod(new QuotationCode(theirObject.quotationCodeString))
```

then you are right, they should replace `String quotationCodeString` in their object with `QuotationCode quotationCode`, and get their ease of use.

On the other hand, if they often do this

```
source.yourMethod(new QuotationCode("xyz-code"))
```

then it is a good idea to define a source for well-known quotation codes, letting your users write this instead:

```
source.yourMethod(QuotationCode.XyzCode)
```

where `XyzCode` is a well-known quotation code which your users were hard-coding as a `String`.

Answer (score 1):

***No own domain types.***

As these kind of data typically are stored in a **database**, and in effect best processed in the database, own domain value classes might be contra-productive in the end. Also declarative business rules, say in `XML` or some DSL are hampered.

It depends on the usage of those data repositories: a DSL like jOOQL, or speedment or JPA. The latter does an Object/Relational mapping, and ID domains are in general replaced by a java class.

For user defined codes there actually is no need for a java type: you will not want to have hard-coded values handled case-by-case. Those should be done declarative. For instance report selection based on invoice category and contract should not be done by nested ifs/switches.

Answer (score 0):

For what you describe, the natural "semantic type" is an enum. The enum type T should override 'T toString()' and implement a 'static T fromString(String)' (or just use 'valueOf()'), which makes it simple for your colleagues to use because the type does its own conversions.

You don't need operator overloading, which introduces more problems than it solves. You have conversion methods, which completely obviate the need for conversion operators, so the comparison to C++ is specious.

Comment: But enumerations in Java have fixed values whereas order numbers are dynamic